# Dynamically aligning text in Next.JS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, fullcalendar, tailwind-css

So I am trying to dynamically align text based on user input.
Ex: User presses 8:00 on a modal button -> left align event title
User presses 8:30-> right align event title

I understand that tailwind is not designed for dynamically changing styles, but am fairly inexperienced with other styling methods (I'm an enthusiastic novice) does anyone have any ideas on how I should tackle this?

What I have right now

The functions that should handle the change:

```
function handleLeftAlign() {
    alignEvent("align-left");
  }

  function handleRightAlign() {
    alignEvent("align-right");
  }

  function alignEvent(alignClass: string) {
    // Update the class for the event with the specified ID (idToAlign)
    setAllEvents((prevEvents) =>
      prevEvents.map((event) =>
        Number(event.id) === Number(idToAlign)
          ? { ...event, alignClass: alignClass }
          : event
      )
    );

    // Close the alignment modal and reset the ID
    setShowAlignModal(false);
    setIdToAlign(null);
  }
```

Where I create the events and their respective styling (currently not working):

```
{events.map((event) => (
              <div
                 className={`fc-event border-2 p-1 m-2 w-full rounded-md ml-auto text-center bg-white ${events.title.alignClass}`}>
                title={event.title}
                key={event.id}
              >
                {event.title}
              </div>
```

The buttons that the user presses:

```
<div className="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:px-6">
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="ml-4 inline-flex justify-center rounded-md bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white 
    shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-500 sm:ml-0 sm:w-auto"
                        onClick={handleLeftAlign}
                      >
                        8:00 AM
                      </button>

                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="ml-8 inline-flex justify-center rounded-md bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white 
    shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-500 sm:ml-2 sm:w-auto"
                        onClick={handleRightAlign}
                      >
                        8:30 AM
                      </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure but might be there is an issue with as you are trying to access events.title.alignClass instead of event.alignClass.

Try this code:-

```
{events.map((event) => (
  <div
    className={`fc-event border-2 p-1 m-2 w-full rounded-md ml-auto text-center bg-white ${event.alignClass}`}
    title={event.title}
    key={event.id}
  >
    {event.title}
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: So this got rid of the error code, but nothing is changing on the client side. I think this has something to do with how tailwind is buggy with changes after runtime, is there any way to do this with styles or clsx?